# Install fresh ERPNEXT on AWS recommendations

Tags: amazon-web-services, erpnext

I need to install ERPNEXT on AWS, I wish if someone can share the recommendation for a good HA setup, also I am stuck in how to put redis on Elasticache?

Comment: For me this is opinion based question.

Answer (score 0):

### Install ERPNEXT:

1. Download the install script

---

For Linux:

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frappe/bench/master/playbooks/install.py

2. Run the install script

---

If you are on a fresh server and logged in as root, use --user flag to create a user and install using that user

`python install.py --develop --user frappe`
For developer setup:

`sudo python install.py --develop`
For production:

`sudo python install.py --production --user frappe`

Reference URL: https://github.com/frappe/bench